# UDP broadcasting with QT

Tags: c++, linux, qt, networking, ubuntu-14.04

I'm searching since two days how to sent a UDP broadcast. I have seen many examples (also the broadcastReceiver and broadcastSender on the qt web site) but they are still not working for me. When I try to send a broadcast, the method QUdpSocket::writeDatagram(..) returns -1 and the datas are not transmitted. I'm on ubuntu 14.04 x64. I wish to know if there is a particular manipulation that I should do to make this broadcast work. Thanks and sorry for my english level.

that is my code

```
 envoyeurUDP=new QUdpSocket(this);
recepteurUDP=new QUdpSocket(this);
//démarrage du serveur pour UDP
if (!recepteurUDP->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4,7878,QUdpSocket::ShareAddress | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint)) {
  qDebug("Impossible de créer la socket en écoute");
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

connect(recepteurUDP, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(lireDatagrams()));
void FileTransferManager::lireDatagrams(){

char* donnees;
while (recepteurUDP->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(recepteurUDP->pendingDatagramSize());
        recepteurUDP->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
        donnees=datagram.data();
    }}
```

and this one to send datagrams

```
void FileTransferManager::sendDatagram(string msg, QHostAddress addr){
QByteArray datagram=msg.data();
    qint64 r=envoyeurUDP->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),  addr, 7878);}
```

and i use it like this :

```
fileManager.sendDatagram("blabla",QHostAddress::Broadcast);
```

here is the output of my ifconfig command:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:a9:63:2d:89:ff
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:0 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          Octets reçus:0 (0.0 B) Octets transmis:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          Packets reçus:5311 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
          Octets reçus:661728 (661.7 KB) Octets transmis:661728 (661.7 KB)

> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ee:65:ab:4f:77
>             inet adr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
>             adr inet6: fe80::baee:65ff:feab:4f77/64 Scope:Lien
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             Packets reçus:14069 erreurs:0 :0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:15529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
>             Octets reçus:6007592 (6.0 MB) Octets transmis:2307422 (2.3 MB)

Comment: Need a short example of code demonstrating the problem. Otherwise you probably aren't going to get any help here. Output from your `ifconfig` would be helpful too, to check that the address is indeed broadcast.

Comment: thank you I have edited my post in order to add the code

Comment: Interesting. What do `error()` and `errorString()` on the datagram socket return after the call to `writeDatagram()` fails?

Comment: errorString() returns "unable to send a message"

Comment: error() returns a SocketError object  and i don't know how to print it. How can i print it?

Comment: It's just an integer. Well, an enum, but no big deal in C++. You can check [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#SocketError-enum) for what the values mean.

Comment: it returns a QAbstractSocket::NetworkError but i'm suprised. I'm on a ad-hoc wifi and the wifi is enable. my ip is visible with ifconfig on the interface wlan0.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because Qt binds the socket automatically on `writeDatagram` (even though the docs don't say that). The NetworkError that you get is one of the most obscure ones, I'm afraid. Try sending a datagram to a non-broadcast address and see what happens (try `127.0.0.1`, localhost, local wlan IP, another IP on the same wlan).

Comment: on a non-broadcast address it works fine. I can view the trafic with wireshark

Comment: Weird. Maybe it's SELinux (try disabling it) or something. Since I can't reproduce the issue, I can't help you any more. I'd try some debugging, stepping into sources and tracing the root of that `-1`.

Comment: You could also just try sending with plain C (search for some example), or using netcat/socat. Then you'll know if it is a Qt problem or OS problem.

Comment: I solved my problem. It was a problem with my firewall. I allow the port 7878 which was blocked by my firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to broadcast messages to any listener:

```
QUdpSocket *udp = new UdpSocket(this);
QByteArray dgram = "hello";
udp->writeDatagram(dgram.data(), dgram.size(), QHostAddress::Broadcast, ipPort);
```